# change an image with the uploaded in other php

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I have the upload form from w3s and works perfectly in my site, but I can't find a way after the user uploads the photo, the new photo to replace an image from another php.
I have my form in admin.php, and after uploading the file I want in photo.php the old image to change with this new one.

This is my code in photo.php

```
<td>
    <figure tabindex="1">
    <img src="img/gal1.jpg" alt="jump, matey" />
    <figcaption>Parlour</figcaption>
    </figure>
</td>
```

Is it possible in this way or I have to rebuild my code?

Comment: form from w3s ? when they start giving form to developers ??

Comment: what do u mean? I am a student and I'm trying to find a way to make it, so I saw in w3s an upload form example and I rebuild it they way it helps me.

Comment: Where do you save uploaded image and which name do you use?

Comment: When the user upload the image, it is saved in a folder img/

Comment: and the name of saved file is gal1.jpg? that means you overwrite the file?

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable with the path of your image. And you must replace the path in

```
<img src="img/gal1.jpg" alt="jump, matey" />
```

to the new path. I mean the part between `src="` and the second `"`, currently it's `img/gal1.jpg`.

Comment: you mean using session?

Answer (score 0):

any php page like after_upload.php

```
   <?php 
    if(isset($_FILES['filename']))
    {
      $new_image = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/sitename/img/".$_FILES['filename']['name'];
    }
    else{

      $new_image = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].'/sitename/img/gal1.jpg";
    }
    ?>

    <td>
        <figure tabindex="1">
        <img src="<?php echo $new_image;?>" alt="jump, matey" />
        <figcaption>Parlour</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </td>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<td>
    <figure tabindex="1">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/img/gal1.jpg" alt="jump, matey" />
        <figcaption>Parlour</figcaption>
    </figure>
</td>
```

Use the absolute path for the image.

Comment: and why this will make any difference ?